# Unclear explanation about analysis an expression

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable. Then suppose we have

$$\mathbf{y}^T \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = 0 \Rightarrow \mathbf{y}^T \nabla^2  f(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{y} \geq0, \text{for all } \mathbf{y} \neq \mathbf{0}.$$

There is a sentence say that:

"For $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \neq \mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{y} \in \{\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\}^{\perp}$. When $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})$ is an eigenvector of $\nabla^2  f(\mathbf{x})$, it means that $\nabla^2  f(\mathbf{x}) \succeq 0$ on the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\{\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\}^{\perp}$ ... "

I do not completely understand this sentence. Do you have better explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\triangledown f(x)\neq0,$ $(\triangledown f(x))^{\perp}$ is a well-defined $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace, and the implication says that whenever $y$ belongs to this subspace, i.e., whenever $y^{T}\triangledown f(x)=0,$ then $y^{T}\triangledown^{2}f(x)y\geq0.$ If we let $V$ be the orthonormal projection matrix onto $(\triangledown f(x))^{\perp}$, then this says that $V^{T}\triangledown^{2} f(x) V$ is positive semidefinite, since any $y=Vx,$ $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will satisfy $y^{T}\triangledown f(x)=0$, and this means that $x^{T}V^{T}\triangledown^{2}f(x)Vx=y^{T}\triangledown^{2}f(x)y\geq0.$ My understanding is that this is what they mean by "positive semidefinite on the subspace $(\triangledown f(x))^{\perp}$." To tell the truth, it is not clear to me why $\triangledown f(x)$ being an eigenvector of $\triangledown^{2} f(x)$ is important for this statement, but it's possible that they define positive semidefiniteness on a subspace in some way that requires this condition.

Comment: Thanks @RideTheWavelet. Why: "If we let $V$ be the orthonormal projection matrix onto $(\triangledown f(x))^{\perp}$, then this says that $V^{T}\triangledown^{2} f(x) V$ is positive semidefinite"?

Comment: One definition for positive semidefiniteness of a square matrix $A$ is that $x^{*}Ax\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},$ which I've shown is true for $V^{T}\triangledown^{2}f(x)V.$